# Integrate a function of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm having this problem of integrating a function that's the solution of a NDSolve multiplied by another function.
I basically compute a cycle wich add at each step the quantity

```
func[x, t] = 
 Gaussian* Evaluate[u[x] /. 
     NDSolve[system, u[x], {x, 0, 6}]]*(Cos[(F - 3 + 0.02*n)*t] - 
     I*Sin[(F - 3 + 0.02*n)*t]);
```

where at each step one solves a different differential equation. At the end the resulting function is given by

```
sum[x,t].
```

The problem comes up when I want to compute the integral of the resulting function multiplied by another function. I want to have as result a function of the time that could be plotted. 
I know that there's some mistake I'm doing when I try to integrate a function that has an interpolating function in it but, after having seen other discussion, I'm still not understanding how it should be done.
Here's the entire code you can run.

```
psi2[x_, t_] = Abs[sum[x, t]]^2
ss[x_, t_] = x*psi2[x, t]
s[t] = Integrate[ss[x_, t_], {x, 0, 6}]
```

If I do this, it gives me problems when one tries to plot s[t].

```
Clear[system, sum, n, integrle]
sum[x_, t_] = 0;
int = 0
F = 2
S = 1
Gaussians = Sqrt[1/(2*Pi)]*E^((-((F + n - 2)/S)^2))
system := {u''[x] == ((9*Pi^2)/4*((x/2)^6 - (x/2)^10) - (F + n))*u[x],
    u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 1};
For[n = 0, n < 100, n++,
 Clear[func, oldSum];
 oldSum[x_, t_] = sum[x, t];
 Clear[sum];
 func[x, t] = 
  Gaussian*Evaluate[u[x] /. 
     NDSolve[system, u[x], {x, 0, 6}]]*(Cos[(F - 3 + 0.02*n)*t] - 
     I*Sin[(F - 3 + 0.02*n)*t]);
 sum[x, t] = oldSum[x, t] + func[x, t];
 ]
psi2[x_, t_] = Abs[sum[x, t]]^2
normalization = Integrate[psi2[x, 0], {x, 0, 6}]
ss[x_, t_] = x*psi2[x, t]
ss2[x_, t_] = x^2*psi2[x, t]
s[t_] = Integrate[ss[x_, t_]/normalization, {x, 0, 6}]
s2[t] = Integrate[ss[x_, t_], {x, 0, 6}]
s3[t_] = Integrate[ss2[x_, t_], {x, 0, 6}]
Plot[{s[t]}, {t, 0, 6}]
Plot[{s2[t]}, {t, 0, 6}]
Plot[{s3[t]}, {t, 0, 6}]
```

Comment: Remove the underscorees on the right side of the definitions `s[t], s2[t],s3[t]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question you try to build a sum over n.

First solve the ode (depending on n)

```
U = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, u , {x, 0, 6}, n]
```

which gives U[n][x]

Summation over n

```
Gaussians = Sqrt[1/(2*Pi)]*E^((-((F + n - 2)/S)^2))
sum[x_, t_] :=Sum[Gaussians*U[n][x]*(Cos[(F - 3 + 0.02*n)*t] - I*Sin[(F - 3 + 0.02*n)*t]), {n,0, 100}]
```

Now you can evaluate `psi2`

```
psi2[x_, t_] := # Conjugate[#] &[sum[x, t]] 
normalization = NIntegrate[psi2[x, 0], {x, 0, 6}]
(*0.219279*)
Table[NIntegrate[x psi2[x, t ], {x, 0, 6}], {t, 0, 6}]/normalization
(*{0.310724, 0.310714, 0.310682, 0.31063, 0.310556, 0.310461, 0.310346}*)
```

But `NIntegrate`  gives some errors concerning convergence.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain the issue very well. The problem is computing the integrals of ss[x,t] and ss2[x,t]. They are the product of x (or x^2) times the function that is the modulus square of sum(which has many interpolation function in it). Both if I try to Integrate and NIntegrate I'm not able to solve them. The aim of the code is plotting as a function of t the division s2[t]/s3[t]. For what I saw it doesn't solve the integrals and it gives me problems when I try to plot s2[t] or s3[t].

Comment: That's the next step. Is `sum[x,t]` from my answer what you tried to calculate?

Comment: The cycle works, it sum 100 times solutions of different differential equations multiplied by a function of time. the problem comes up when one tries to compute the integral of x*Abs[sum[x,t]].I want to obtain a function of time that can be plotted. I have to compute this integral and the integral of x^2*Abs[sum[x,t]] and plot their division as a funtion of time.